# How to read bz2 files into dataframes using pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I can read a json file into a dataframe in Pyspark using

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('GetDetails').getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.json("path to json file")
```

However, when i try to read a bz2(compressed csv) into a dataframe it gives me an error. I am using:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('GetDetails').getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.load("path to bz2 file")
```

Could you please help correct me?

Comment: What error did you get? Try to include that error in your question.

Comment: I believe the error contains this clue: "Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: file:path/to/json.bz2 is not a Parquet file. expected magic number at tail [80, 65, 82, 49] but found [0, 108, 106, -40]" as by default `spark.read.load` expects "parquet" format.

Answer (score 2):

The method `spark.read.load()` has an optional parameter `format` which by default is 'parquet'.

So, for your code to work it should look like this:

```py
df = spark.read.load("data.json.bz2", format="json")
```

Also, `spark.read.json` will perfectly work for compressed JSON files, e.g.:

```py
df = spark.read.json("data.json.bz2")
```